# On which Stack Exchange site should I post a web application migration question?

Tags: support, site-recommendation

On which SE site should I post a web application migration question? I have posted the question on [Web Applications](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/q/158867/) and [Software Engineering](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/431691/); it's been closed on Web Apps.

The Software Engineering post:

> I have an application written in C# which I want to migrate from a local server provider to Azure.
>
> The idea is to migrate the whole application, in other words, I need that the application which is hosted on a local server provider works exactly the same after migrating the application to Azure without doing anything extra I need to: "copy and paste".
>
> I have an idea of how to perform this operation but another important thing is that the application should keep working on the local service provider for a while until the migration is at a 100%.

Comment: Do not cross post on multiple sites in the SE network.

Comment: Your question is way too broad to be answered on any SE site. You need a tutorial, a course or a consultant.

Comment: Stack Exchange is not obligated to provide every asker a venue to get their problem solved. If we're telling you that this question won't work anywhere, it won't work anywhere here. We're sorry, but we can't help you solve your problem because it just doesn't work here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tl; Dr: The SE Network hasn't a site for the question provided as example.

---

The question doesn't look to be a good fit for Q/A model of the SE Network so it's very unlikely that you will get an answer pointing you to an existing site that accept it. By the way, on Software Engineering the question was closed too; so far it got a comment requesting to show what you have tried.

First thing that you should have in mind is that the SE Network doesn't pretend to have a site for every possible question, even for Information Technologies professionals / web applications.

Regarding the referred comment in Software Engineering, you might have to start looking for related questions to learn what kind of *help* is being handled at that site. Look at the tag wikis as they might have directions / tips about how you could focus your question.

Related

- [Where can I ask a question about developing web applications?](https://webapps.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4685/88163)
- [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange sites do I post on?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/129598/289691)